# 404 & 501 errors with Microsoft's Web Application Stress Tool

Tags: webapplicationstresstool

I've recorded a few scripts with this tool, but when I run it, 100% of my results codes are either 404 (Not Found) or 501 (Not Implemented).

How can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, before you run the test, you have to specify the host you wish to test near the top of the screen. I remember finding this kind of odd, and thinking the host should have been recorded with the script, but it only recorded the paths as part of the script.

I could be thinking of a different program entirely, forgive me if that's the case.

Comment: That's it Chris - didn't see the forest for the trees. You'd think the default behavior would be to set the host to the actual host used during recording, rather than always setting it to localhost. Thanks for the help!